# C# - How to GET actual height of ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, size

I know `ComboBox.Height` cannot be set easily. Can be changed with the `Font`. But I need to know it's final height. It doesn't update before the window and controls are displayed.

How can I *calculate* it ? When I run this the button is not below but behind the combo box:

```
// my forms must be disigned by code only (no designer is used)
public class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
        box.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 100, FontStyle.Regular);
        Controls.Add(box);

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "hello world";
        button.SetBounds(box.Left, box.Bottom, 256, 32);
        button.SetBounds(box.Left, box.Height, 256, 32); // doesn't work either
        Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: It inherits from control so whats wrong with the [`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.height.aspx) property?

Comment: @Sayse I guess the OPs problem is the ComboBox popup list covering other controls on his form. `Height` will only return the TextBox part control height.

Comment: @Sayse It doesn't update until the window and `ComboBox` is visible.

Comment: I highly doubt that is true, it should be possible after initialize component and in the `OnLoad` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `ComboBox.Bottom` property will not be updated to compensate for the font size until the `ComboBox` has been drawn.

The solution is to dynamically add your controls in the `Form.Load` event instead of the constructor:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
    box.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 100, FontStyle.Regular);
    Controls.Add(box);

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "hello world";
    button.SetBounds(box.Left, box.Bottom, 256, 32); 
    Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thanks! Also `Resize` event of the `ComboBox` works, too.